# Requiring a folder with index.js

Tags: node.js, typescript

I'm trying to require a folder with index.js by specifying a folder name

```
import xyz = require("./xyz");
```

and get a compilation error "*Unable to resolve external module xyz. Module cannot be aliased to a non-module type.*"

If I specify index

```
import xyz = require("./xyz/index");
```

it works.

If I do

```
var xyz = require("./xyz");
```

it works, but I get no intellisense on xyz.

Is that feature not supported in Typescript ?

Comment: As snover metioned. Fyi Just go with `require("./xyz/index");`

Comment: There is a feature request you can vote on : http://typescript.codeplex.com/workitem/2125

Comment: I don't even think this is working in 1.0RC (`./xyz/index`), at least I can't get it to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, TypeScript does not follow the module resolution rules of Node.js, as they are quite specific to that platform. TypeScript supports multiple platforms that do not follow Node.js conventions.

The TypeScript specification states, about relative module resolution:

> If the import declaration specifies a relative external module name, the name is resolved relative to the directory of the referencing module’s file path. The program must contain a module with the resulting file path or otherwise an error occurs. For example, in a module with the file path
>   ‘C:/src/ui/main’, the external module names ‘./editor’ and ‘../lib/io’ reference modules with the file
>   paths ‘C:/src/ui/editor’ and ‘C:/src/lib/io’.